# How to store value from JTextField to a local variable?

Tags: java

I want to store the value from TextField to a local variable so I can get the value by reference it from other package

I have tried a few way to solve this myself, but I found the value null.

```
private JButton execute = new JButton("Execute");
public JTextField radius = new JTextField(5);


    // Find the result.
    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    add(execute, gc);

    List<MainController> listeners = new ArrayList<MainController>();
    execute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (MainController listener : listeners) {
                listener.notify(radius.getText());
            }
        }
    });
    add(execute, gc);
```

and the one below is the class I want to get the value

```
public class MainController extends JFrame {

private int radius;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void notify(String rad) {
    radius = Integer.parseInt(rad);
    System.out.println(radius);
}
```

}

What should I do to store the value to a local variable so that I can get the value from other package

Comment: An anonymous inner class can't write to a local variable. You have to turn the local variable into a field of the class in which this method sits for example.

Comment: it still gives me null even I've assign a value. How to fix it? @GhostCat

Comment: Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. You have to show all relevant code. Nobody can tell you what is wrong in your code is doing when we can't see it!

Comment: I have update it, I think this is all the relevant code. Could you please tell me where is my problem? @GhostCat

Comment: You have an **empty** list there. You have to **add** an instance of that interface (aka your main class) to that list. Don't just blindly copy paste code from answers! You have to understand what you are doing. In your code, that list is empty, and thus no listener is ever notified.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have, I understand that when you press the button you want to save the text inside radius o a local variable, strRad, so later on you can access it from another class. If that is the case then you can maybe create a listener pattern yourself and then have something like:

```
private List<YourListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>(); 
.
.
.
execute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (YourListener listener : listeners) {
           listener.notify(radius.getText());
        }
    }
});
```

You have to create the YourListener interface other class that wants to access the JTextField value would implement it.

Comment: but how to create the listener interface, my other class is MainController. Could you please give me the example code of how to create the listener intterface please?

Comment: I have update the code to show the other class I want to get the value